# OPENERP 7: _BaseModel__view_look_dom_arch error

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

This is the generated error:

```
File "/home/sample/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line
1776,in __view_look_dom
xarch, xfields = relation.__view_look_dom_arch(cr, user, f, view_id, ctx)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_BaseModel__view_look_dom_arch'
2013-03-21 09:19:32,668 3683 ERROR bpl_db openerp.tools.convert: Parse error in
/home/sample/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_view.xml:276: 
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="iamsample_form">
        <field name="name">iamsample.form</field>
        <field name="model">sample.class</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Sample Class" version="7.0">
                <sheet>
```

I've read some related posts but couldn't find the answer for my issue. I also tried to override the form but this also gave me basemodel error. The only way for me to create a view of it is to XPath my fields to the existing form/class.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of Issue with my sequence.xml file and the  onetomany mapping in model class. This can be solved by doing some changes  on `openerp.py` file

Comment: But I did some changes on openerp.py and still failed to fix it. 

It came up when i added a new .py file and .xml file in the openerp and fixed it to be okay with the module and then basemodel error in that form but i didnt do anything or change that xml file and its .py file...

But back to my previous module without the adding of new .py and .xml, it dont have an error. cant figure it out whats wrong. Can you help me to find out?

Comment: have a look here https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/1111340 ..that link would help

Comment: I already saw that before but it didnt help. I tried to update the module without it and back it again and re-update it but it still the same error. Even in new database didnt work. The only way that i can do is xpath otherwise it is basemodel error. :(

Comment: What does a base model error mean?

And also what does this mean: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_BaseModel__view_look_dom_arch' ?

Comment: i think you need to make changes on __init.py file ..see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919525/openerp-7-adding-field-to-existing-module-xml-validate-error

Comment: I also did that too before... but still failed. :(

Comment: I think the edit you are making in the file is wrong ..since i havnt experienced this issue i dont know more about it ..you need to make edits clear otherwise it wont work

Comment: I experienced it before.. i cant remember how did i fixed it but one thing i know is that i edited some in the openerp.py.....

but i tried it with this... it failed.. so the only option that is left is xpath. Ill just xpath it for now but will try to find it soon... or someone will give the answer to this problem. Thanks.